# How to run Fortran77 code from an .src file?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am very new to Fortran and trying to run (alleged) Fortran77 code. This code however is supplied in an .src file.

When opening this file in notepad, the code looks like Fortran but with seemingly random numbers and line breaks added.

The code does not compile in Visual Studio/Intel Visual Fortran.

Has anyone ever seen this and can help me?

A code snippet:

```
    70 FORMAT(1H1,10X,*KOUNT = *,I4,18X,*R = *,E13.5//)
      GO TO 503
  513 WRITE(6,504) KOUNT,X1
  504 FORMAT(1H1,10X,*KOUNT = *,I4,18X,*X = *,E13.5//)
  503 CONTINUE
      WRITE(6,610) ZSHIFT,XSHIFT,XTHR,ZLIFT,YMOM
  610 FORMAT(10X,*Z MOMENT AXIS = *,E11.3,5X,*X MOMENT AXIS = *,E11.3/
     1                     10X,*THRUST = *,E11.3,5X,*LIFT = *,E11.3,5X
     1,*PITCHING MOMENT = *,E11.3)
      IF(IS(3).NE.0.AND.KOUNT.NE.0.AND.ISIM.EQ.0) WRITE(6,621) XTHRC,ZLI
     1FTC,YMOMC
  621 FORMAT(* CONTACT  *     ,*THRUST = *,E11.3,5X,*LIFT = *,E11.3,5X
     1,*PITCHING MOMENT = *,E11.3)
      IF(IS(1).NE.0.AND.KOUNT.NE.0.AND.ISIM.EQ.0 ) WRITE(6,622) XTHRS,ZL
     1IFTS,YMOMS
  622 FORMAT(*   SHOCK  *     ,*THRUST = *,E11.3,5X,*LIFT = *,E11.3,5X
     1,*PITCHING MOMENT = *,E11.3)
      WRITE(6,623)
  623 FORMAT(/)
      DO 71 J=1,JMAX
      IF(J.GT.JCALC) GO TO 71
      IF(J.GT.JINT  ) GO TO 2260
      IF(XJ.NE.0..OR.XJ1.NE.0.) GO TO 505
      WRITE(6,506) J,HE(1),HE(4),TH(J),HE(5)
  506 FORMAT(//10X,*J = *,I2,24X,A5,A3     ,E13.5,/4X,*I*,6X,A1 ,10X,
     1*P*,10X,*Q*, 9X,*PHE*, 8X,*SI*,10X,*M*,10X,*H*, 9X,*PHI*
     1,8X,*RHO*,8X,*GAM*,9X,*T*)
      GO TO 510
  505 IF(XJ1.EQ.0.) GO TO 507
```

[Screenshot of the code in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcTNS.png)

My Google-Fu is not turning up anything. I have tried copy and pasting the code, which throws a lot of errors. Removing the numbers and line breaks seems to resolve some of the errors. Using the gFortran compiler also does not work.

Comment: The code is to long to provide in plain text in the post. However I will add a snippet.

Comment: That code snippet brings back some (not great) memories of Fortran77 from college. :)  Stuff like this is why they invented structured programming; this sort of code motivated the famous "Go To Considered Harmful" letter.

Comment: Could you also please give any error message or such that tells you that the compiler doesn't accept the program?  There may be other aspects my answer missed.

Answer (score 2):

Those "random numbers and line breaks" are symptoms of the Fortran source being in *fixed form*.  This is consistent with the code dating back to when Fortran 77 was the thing.

You need to tell the compiler to treat the source as this form, either using an appropriate file extension (such as `.f`) or using a compiler option.  Options for the compiler [are](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/691732):

- `/fixed` as a command line option;
- or under `Language > Source File Format (/free, /fixed)`

---

In summary, fixed form sources has the first few numbers as a line label and the numbers (here, but could be other characters) in the sixth column as statement continuation markers.  So, those strangely placed line breaks are not signifying the end of a statement when there is a `1` in the sixth column of the following line.